# Page redirect when not logged in

Tags: mysql, servlets

I am designing a web application in SERVLET and JSP with Tomcat as server and MySQL as back end. I have a login page. I want a user to visit various pages only after he/she is logged in. But what happens in my case is, if I give the page name in URL, I can visit the page even when I am not logged in! How to do I achieve it? please help.

Comment: Read about servlet filter it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a filter to intercept the servlet and jsp。

Comment: Judge  the value in the session is null or not,if true,redirect the login page. the filter is executed before servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Protect the pages you want to require authentication for with a security constraint. You define those in web.xml. The container will then ensure that only authenticated users can access the pages.